# JS - Trying to automate Likes on a discussion board

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to automate Likes on a discussion board, and I am doing following steps -

- Open Console in Chrome
- Execute following 2 statements

> ```
> let btnLike = document.querySelectorAll('.action-like')
> btnLike.forEach(btn => btn.click())
> ```

However the Like button acts as a toggle, and if any of the postings were already Liked, the above statements are going to Unlike them (if a post is Liked, the "Like" button is a member of class .action-like.is-liked)

Is there a way to Select only the elements that are yet to be Liked ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:not(.is-liked)`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.action-like:not(.is-liked)');
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks a million!